# batch processing proof of the number of jobs' relationship with service time and waiting time

Tags: math, operating-system, proof, calculus, differentiation

The classical batch processing system ignores the cost of increased waiting time for users. Consider a single batch characterized by the following parameters:

M average mounting time

T  average service time per job

N  number of jobs

S   unit price of service time

W  unit price of waiting time per user

Show that the optimal batch size that minimizes the cost of service time and 
waiting time per user (within a single batch) is

[image: Equation To Be Proven]

Comment: I am not sure where to start... I was told of an example where Total Cost = [S / (T*N)] + [(W*N) / M]

Now if you differentiate TC wrt N this you get :

0 = -  [S / (T * (N(sqred) ))] + W / M but I am not sure where the original equation is coming from

Comment: what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a formula for the cost of service time and a formula for the cost of the waiting time per user.
You'll find that these will be S/TN and WN/M respectively.
Adding these gives you total cost. This is how that formula is created.